# Fetch name of company from Google Finance page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to get the name of a company into a Google spreadsheet.
The `GOOGLEFINANCE` function doesn't include the name of the company in its attributes, so I'm trying to create a custom function for that.

So, for IBM, for example, I can fetch the URL:

```
https://www.google.com/finance?q=ibm
```

And using Javascript, I'm trying to get the text of the name using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('appbar-snippet-primary')[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML
```

Which is returning:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do that inside apps scripts it wont be possible, the version of javascript in apps script does not contain the document object, therefore you won't be able to do it like that.
If you return that response to the client(where the javascript contains the document object) in order to look for the item in that way, you should have first add the information to that object.

a possible solution would be to treat the result of the urlfetch as string and then look for the information you require.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo You mean grabbing the whole page html as a string to GAS and then search within it? That seems like a heavy duty for grabbing a single name, but perhaps it'll work!